# Add button to header of table in angularjs

Tags: html, css, angularjs, ngtable, dynamic-tables

How do I add a button to the header of the table. I'm using ng-table-dynamic and I have no idea.

[image]

I tried to use headerTemplateURL attribute but it doesn't work.

I don't want to use position to do the trick.

p/s: https://codepen. io/trungducng/pen/RwbqJpb

Comment: Show me your code please.

Comment: URL is not working

Comment: @Alok https://codepen.io/trungducng/pen/RwbqJpb?editors=1010

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `headerTemplateURL` and insert url of the component to it:

"headerTemplateURL": "button.html"